# Рекурсия в javascript

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Нужно создать рекурсию, чтобы функция вызывала саму себя. Был создан такой костыль:

```
function startSlider(items, delay) {
        $(items[0]).fadeIn(300)
            .delay(delay)
            .fadeOut(300)
            .promise()
            .done(function() {
                items.splice(0, 1);
                if (items.length > 0)
                {
                    startSlider(items, delay);
                }
                else
                {
                    //sliderRetry($(".offer-scrin"), delay);
                    startSlider(items, delay);
                }
        });
    }
    function sliderRetry(items, delay) {
        return startSlider(items, delay);
    }
```

Это все работает, но на страницах, где эта функция не нужна, вызывается ошибка "много рекурсий".

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: А чем определяется, что "функция не нужна"? Нельзя поставить проверку на наличие элемента для слайдера? И если его нет - `return false;`. Например, первой строчкой функции `startSlider` сделать `if (!$(items[0]).length) return false;`

Comment: Спасибо, так работает. Но для чистоты кода, можно ли как-то избавиться от второй функции? Чтобы функция вызывала саму себя, а не через другую?

Comment: Так вообще непонятно зачем Вам вторая функция. `sliderRetry` нигде в коде не упоминается. А вот `startSlider` сам себя итак запускает.

Comment: @cyadvert Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Самый разумный вариант, как мне кажется, это поставить проверку на наличие элемента для слайдера.
Если элемента нет, то функция будет возвращать `false`, и ошибка перестанет появляться. Лучше всего это сделать в самом начале.

```
function startSlider(items, delay) {
    if (!$(items[0]).length) return false; //если элемента нет - выход
    $(items[0]).fadeIn(300)
        .delay(delay)
        .fadeOut(300)
и т.д.
```

---

И еще, не совсем понятно, зачем нужна функция `sliderRetry`? В представленном Вами коде она нигде не используется...